# Seeing a package version but not able to install it

Tags: apt, package-management

Here is what I have tried so far

```
$ apt-cache policy couchdb
couchdb:
  Installed: 3.0.0~bionic
  Candidate: 3.0.0~bionic
  Version table:
 *** 3.0.0~bionic 500
        500 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.3.1~bionic 500
        500 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb bionic/main amd64 Packages
     2.3.0~bionic 500
        500 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb bionic/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.0~bionic 500
        500 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb bionic/main amd64 Packages
     2.1.2~bionic 500
        500 https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

I would like to install version 2.3.1 so I went ahead with :

```
$ sudo apt-get install couchdb=2.3.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.3.1' for 'couchdb' was not found
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to do

```
$ sudo apt-get install couchdb=2.3.1~bionic
```

Answer (score 0):

The log says that you have installed the version 3.0.0 of "couchdb", so you would have to unistall it first before install the 2.3.1.

Before even that, i suggest you to check in you synaptic package manager if you have avaible that version. If not the you should have to search a repository that grant i t to you, or a .deb package.

I discourage install things from the terminal, ecause you can mess all up(i have to format 3 times this month)

As i can see in your log, you have bionic(ubuntu 18.04) so i checked in my repository and i dont have such package.

I found [this](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.1/install/unix.html) dumentation, maybe it will help you with something